# Copy multiple files in java

Tags: java

i tried

```
 private boolean CopyFiles(List<File> selected)
{
    try {
        File mNewFile = new File("/home/ubuntu/Desktop");
        mNewFile.createNewFile();
        FileUtils.copyFile(selected,mNewFile);
        return true;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CommonMethod.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

    }   



    return false;
}
```

in above code for copy file FileUtild.copyFile(File src, File dest) method dose not support for multiple file copy any idea for that?

Comment: Hi, this is not a JavaFX related question. Please remove the JavaFX tag and add a Java tag.

Comment: It is usually more efficient to copy one file at a time in a loop.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are using org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils and that "/home/ubuntu/Desktop" is a directory.
In this case you can do it like this:

```
nNewFile.mkdirs();
for(File f : selected) {
    FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(f, nNewFile);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils` to copy files from one location to another

```
private void copyFiles(List<File> selected, File destinationDirectory)
{
    for(File file : selected){
       try {
          if (!destinationDirectory.exists())
            destinationDirectory.mkdir();
          FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(file,destinationDirectory);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(CommonMethod.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }   
    }
}
```